# Circuit with four light bulbs and four batteries

Tags: batteries, light

The circuit has four identical batteries and four identical light bulbs. The current in each bulb is IL and the current provided by each battery is IB.

What is the relation between IB and IL and why?

[image: The circuit]

Comment: Homework question. What did you get and why, then we will help.

Comment: @Passerby I am 1st class high-school student, and this question is from 2nd class. Using my knowledge i figured that there are more than four conturs and at least IL > IB. But, I don't have the certain knowledge but electronics is my hobby and I am hoping for help from a professional(or at least person with solid knowledge)

Comment: Why does IL > IB?

Comment: I think that one light bulb gets current from more than 1 battery, so IL>IB

Comment: Imagine that you have a voltmeter, and you clipped one of the voltmeter wires somewhere in the circuit. Can you predict any of the voltages that you could measure by attaching the other voltmeter wire?

Comment: @TomAnderson I think it depends on where I clip the other wire

Comment: Are there any spots in the circuit where you can clip the other wire and predict what the voltage will be?

Comment: I think on the battery terminals

Comment: Great! Every point in the circuit is attached to a battery terminal. Now predict all the voltages are that you would read with the meter. Don't move the wire that you clipped on, just predict the voltages you could measure at all the battery terminals. What voltages do you predict?

Comment: The one thing about an ideal battery is that it _always enforces_ its voltage. So, if you consider any of the light bulbs, the one thing that you can be sure of is that it has _exactly_ 2x the battery voltage over it.  Does that help?

Comment: @TomAnderson I would get 1,2,3,4 for example or 10,20,30,40. I think you get my point

Comment: @neonzeon So from your answer at least IL=2IB

Comment: You aren't quite there yet. Check which way the batteries are pointing, and find the right voltages.

Comment: Badly drawn circuit. Do the horizontal and vertical wires between batteries cross over, or are they joined at the center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IB is twice that if IL.

Each battery is in two current loops. Where each bulb is in one current loop. The current splits in half to power each loop.